# Changing the font size of a range element

Tags: python, ms-word, com

I have the following Python code which is supposed to change the font of a specific range of a Microsoft Word document:

```
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.DisplayAlerts = 0
doc = word.Documents.Open("d:/test2.docx")
par = doc.Paragraphs    
par(1).Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
rng = par(2).Range    
rng.Text = u"works just fine"
rng.Font.Size = 30
rng.Font.Name = "Georgia"
```

It works fine when the string assigned to `rng.Text` is English but when it is in
Persian, for example `rng.Text=u"سلام"`, or Hebrew `rng.Text=u"אקדיא"`, the font settings are not applied and have no effect. I don't know whether it's an encoding issue or not. Any ideas how I can set the font settings when the string is not in English?

Answer (score 0):

Georgia is not a unicode font; it doesn't have the characters you're trying to use, so the font settings can't be applied.  Try a font that supports unicode (I believe Tahoma and Lucida Sans do) and see if that works.

Comment: I've tried other fonts(specially ones which are made for Persian language), but no luck so far. have you tested this?

Answer (score 0):

Font.Size property is for left-to-right languages.
For right-to-left languages such as Persian or Hebrew MS Word VBA provides a special SizeBi property.
So, in your code, instead of

```
rng.Font.Size = 30
```

write

```
rng.Font.SizeBi = 30
```